AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'. kivy: table generator screen
I started working with kivy language some days ago and I need a help. I want to program a Menu and when click in DataTable, a table with data is displayed. However when I run the following code, there is the error: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'getattr'.
Python code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
import pandas as pd
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.behaviors.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.properties import ListProperty 
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation

Window.size = (800,600)

class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Menu(Screen):
    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.bind(on_request_close = self.confirmacao)

    def confirmacao(self,*args,**kwargs):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical',padding=10,spacing=10)
        botoes = BoxLayout(padding = 10, spacing = 10)

        pop = Popup(title = 'Are you sure you want exit?\n(Changes that you have made may not be saved)',content=box,size_hint=(None,None),
                    size = (150,150))
        
        sim = Botao(text = 'Yes',on_release = App.get_running_app().stop)
        nao = Botao(text = 'No',on_release = pop.dismiss)

        botoes.add_widget(sim)
        botoes.add_widget(nao)
        
        atencao = Image(source = 'C:/Users/willi/Área de Trabalho/Masters/ANN_app/atencao.png')

        box.add_widget(atencao)
        box.add_widget(botoes)

        animText = Animation(color=(0,0,0,1)) + Animation(color=(1,1,1,1))
        animText.repeat = True
        animText.start(sim)
        anim = Animation(size=(400,220),duration=0.2,t='out_back')
        anim.start(pop)

        pop.open()
        return True
    
class DataTable(Screen):
    def __init__(self,table='', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        
        data_df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/willi/Área de Trabalho/Masters/Data_ANN_Filtered.xlsx" )
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
        data = df.to_dict()

        column_titles = [x for x in data.keys()]
        rows_length = len(data[column_titles[0]])
        self.columns = len(column_titles)

        screen_height = Window.height
        max_height = 70  # Set the maximum row height
        min_font_size = 10  # Set the minimum font size


        self.ids.table_floor_layout.add_widget(Label(text="Your DataFrame", size_hint_y=None, height=30))
        
        table_data = []
        
        for y in column_titles:

            table_data.append({'text':str(y),'size_hint_y':None,'height':30,'font_size':'15sp','bcolor':(221/255,108/255,21/255,1)}) #append the data

        for z in range(rows_length):
            for y in column_titles:
                if data[y][z] < 0.0001 or data[y][z] > 9999:
                    table_data.append({'text':str('{:.4E}'.format(data[y][z])),'size_hint_y':None,'height':20,'bcolor':(221/255,108/255,21/255,1),'font_size':'15sp'}) #append the data
                else:
                    table_data.append({'text':str('{:.3f}'.format(data[y][z])),'size_hint_y':None,'height':20,'bcolor':(221/255,108/255,21/255,1),'font_size':'15sp'}) #append the data

        self.ids.table_floor_layout.cols = self.columns #define value of cols to the value of self.columns
        self.ids.table_floor.data = table_data #add table_data to data value

class Botao(ButtonBehavior,Label):
    cor = ListProperty([221/255,108/255,21/255,1])
    cor2 = ListProperty([0,0,1,1])

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Botao,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.atualizar()

    def on_pos(self,*args):
        self.atualizar()

    def on_size(self,*args):
        self.atualizar()

    def on_press(self,*args):
        self.cor, self.cor2 = self.cor2,self.cor

    def on_release(self,*args):
        self.cor2, self.cor = self.cor, self.cor2

    def on_cor(self,*args):
        self.atualizar()

    def atualizar(self,*args):
        self.canvas.before.clear()
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(rgba=self.cor)
            Ellipse(size=(self.height,self.height),
                    pos = self.pos)
            Ellipse(size=(self.height,self.height),
                    pos=(self.x+self.width-self.height,self.y))
            Rectangle(size=(self.width-self.height,self.height),
                      pos=(self.x+self.height/2.0,self.y))
            
class Soft_lv(App):
    def build(self):
        return Gerenciador()


Soft_lv().run()

My kivy code:
<Gerenciador>
    Menu:
        name: 'Menu'
    DataTable:
        name: 'DataTable'

<Menu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 200 #margem
        spacing: 10 #espaco
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size #app inteiro
                pos: self.pos # app inteiro
                #size: 100,200 #100x200
                #pos: 0,100 #posicao
        Image:
            source: 'C:/Users/willi/Área de Trabalho/Masters/ANN_app/logo.jpeg'
            #source: 'C:/Users/willi/Área de Trabalho/Masters/ANN_app/aleat.jpeg'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 200
            allow_stretch: True
        Label:
            id: label
            text: 'WELCOME TO WILL PREDICT!'
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Label:
            id: label
            text: 'SELECT ONE OF THE FOLLOWING OPTIONS TO START!'
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Botao:
            text:'DataTable'
            color: 0,0,0,1
            font_size: self.parent.height/55
            on_release: app.root.current = 'DataTable'
        Botao:
            text: 'Load File'
            font_size: self.parent.height/55
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Botao:
            text: 'Tutorial'
            font_size: self.parent.height/55
            color: 0,0,0,1
        Botao:
            text: 'Exit'
            font_size: self.parent.height/55
            color: 0,0,0,1
            on_release: root.confirmacao()



<DataTable>:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 40 #margem
        spacing: 10 #espaco
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size #app inteiro
                pos: self.pos # app inteiro

        Label:
            text: 'Confirm if it is your dataframe...'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            color: 221/255,108/255,21/255,1
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            Botao:
                text: 'Yes'
                size_hint_x: 0.5
            Botao:
                text: 'No, I want to upload other'
                size_hint_x: 0.5
        RecycleView:
            viewclass: 'CustomLabel'
            id: table_floor
            RecycleGridLayout:
                id: table_floor_layout
                cols: 5
                default_size: (None, 250)
                default_size_hint: (1, None)
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                spacing: 5

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    bcolor: (1,1,1,1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.bcolor
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

When I return just the menu or just datatable in the Soft_lv class, there isn't any problem. Probably, it is in RecycleView... I am not sure about it...
